# On windows Scroll count item of class and the execute function on particular item scroll in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.5){  
newAjaxCallfunction();
   }});
```

**I have this code working but my issue is different**
When page load i have 10 item by default to show , i want when i scroll to 9 item then reset item to come which means trigger newAjaxCallfunction(), items are coming from newAjaxCallfunction(). 
I have same class for all item first 10 also called rowHeight class and it is in loop so first ten class are by default and reset item which will come also have same class name .

Answer (score 0):

Use the particular `div` and handle scroll on that div by using `innerHeight()` function and `scrollHeight`

```
$('.scroll').scroll(function() {
  var lastItemHeight = $(this).children().last().height();
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).innerHeight() - lastItemHeight) {
    console.log($(this).scrollTop() + '-' + $(this).innerHeight() + '-' + $(this)[0].scrollHeight + '-' + lastItemHeight)
  }
});
```

```js
$('.scroll').scroll(function() {
  var lastItemHeight = $(this).children().last().height();
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).innerHeight() - lastItemHeight) {
    console.log($(this).scrollTop() + '-' + $(this).innerHeight() + '-' + $(this)[0].scrollHeight + '-' + lastItemHeight)
  }
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.child {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but .scroll or i have rowHeight class name has 10 item in it and i want trigger newAjaxCallfunction when 9th item is scrolled.

Comment: Use the last element's height to calculate the last elemets starting position. i have updated the answer. upvote & accept the answer if it helped, so that it would be useful for some other one like you

Comment: what is .scroll . my div has class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-no-padding hidden-xs rowHeight" only and it is looped 10 times for first time then when i scroll to 9item of prodheight class then should fire newAjaxCallfunction().

Comment: `scroll` will be the class name of the parent of those 10 elements. what do u want more ? i have answered the qustion still you are not convinced? :D if you have some other issue, then ask in a separate question

Comment: and you have posted only a small piece of code. we are trying to help you, not trying to get any benefits from you, okay? I have added the code which could make you get idea about how to deal with this situations. But you want me to code your complete page?

Comment: i am trying to change the logic . I am new to jquery so wanted to get much more idea clear not want to get coded whole page . Off-course thanks i am trying different logic with your suggestion .

Comment: Ok. NP @KumarSubham I have added a demo for you. I updated the the answer. I hope it helps